# Normalisation factor $\psi_0$ for wave function $\psi = \psi_0 \sin(kx-\omega t)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, hilbert-space, normalization

I know that if I integrate probabilitlity $|\psi|^2$ over a whole volume $V$ I am supposed to get 1. This equation describes this.

$$\int \limits^{}_{V} \left|\psi \right|^2 \, \textrm{d} V = 1\\$$

How would we calculate a normalisation factor $\psi_0$ for two simple wave functions like:

$$
\begin{split}
\psi &= \psi_0 \sin(kx-\omega t)\\
\psi &= \psi_0 e^{i(kx-\omega t)}
\end{split}
$$

I know this is quite a basic question, but I have to straighten this out so I can continue reading QM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jerry Schirmer's answer applies in an infinite space. If you put the system in a box there is no problem: the normalized wavefunction is $\mathrm{e}^{ikx}/\sqrt{V}$. This is the usual theoretical device to make everything nice and well behaved. Then we take the limit $V\rightarrow\infty$ at the end of the day and, if we've done our job correctly, all of the $V$ dependence should drop out of the final answer. It's not too unreasonable either, since we don't actually *know* that the universe is infinite. Infinite *for all practical purposes* might as well just be a big box.

---

EDIT in response to comments:

Assume we operate in a box of volume $V$ (in any number of dimensions - interpret as length, area or volume as appropriate). We want to find the normalisation factor $N$ for the wavefunction $\psi = N \mathrm{e}^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$. So we calculate the norm of the wavefunction, which must be equal to one:

$$ \begin{array}{lcl}
1 &=& \int\mathrm{d}x\ \psi^\star \psi \\
  &=& \int\mathrm{d}x\ N^\star N \\
  &=& \left| N \right|^2 V
\end{array}$$

So $N$ has a magnitude of $1/\sqrt{V}$ and an arbitrary phase which can be chosen to make it real and positive.

Comment: Could you please show a derivation that led you to your anwser that normalisation factor is $e^{ikx}/\sqrt{V}$?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, really.  In the continuum, the "free particle wavefunction" is an abstraction to make the math easier.  In a real context, you'd talk about a Wave envelope $\phi(x) = \int dk A(k)e^{ikx}$, where $A(k)$ is a bounded function that guarantees that $\int\phi^{*}\phi$ is finite and normalizable.  Note that this is the generalization to the continuum of saying that $\phi(x) = \sum a_{i}\phi_{i}$, where the $\phi_{i}$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.  It's just that, in the continuum, we have an infinite number of eigenstates.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a comment but I feel it's important enough that it warrants some space as an answer. Note carefully that the wavefunction $\psi=\psi_0 \sin(kx-\omega t)$ is **not** a solution to the free-particle Schrödinger equation.

This is easy to see mathematically. The kinetic term, $-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$, will return a sine term, while the single time derivative in the total energy term will return a cosine. These can never be proportional.

More physically, you can decompose that wavefunction into two complex exponentials, as $\psi=\frac1{2i}\psi_0(e^{i(kx-\omega t)}-e^{-i(kx-\omega t)})$. The first term is OK, but the second one simply isn't: it's a plane wave going to the left (which is ok) multiplied by the phase $e^{+i\omega t}$. This phase represents a *negative* energy, which is not physical in a free particle with purely positive kinetic energy.

Sine-like wavefunctions do happen in quantum theory, most notably for the infinite square well. There the energy eigenfunctions are of the form $\sin(n\pi x/L)$ to vanish at $x=0$ and $x=L$, but the time dependence is 
$$\psi_n(x,t)=A_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)e^{-i\omega_n t},$$
and the total energy is positive. Beware!